# Request throttle or Spam protection on direct line endpoints (Bot Framework)?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Does the Bot Framework's direct line endpoints throttles requests or has Spam protection?

We will soon put a bot online and are expecting heavy traffic. We're currently executing load tests and are having problems (timeouts) when multiple connections are made to direct line simultaneously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform load tests directly against your bot's endpoint. Load tests should not be done through direct line.

Comment: We are now testing our bot endpoint directly. We are concern though that when our bot goes live, we might have problems with the load on the bot framework. Our bot will be reachable from messenger and web chat and going through the bot framework. Is there any way for us to ensure that the bot framework will handle the load when we go live?

Thanks!